# Change Kerberos ticket cache location for java

Tags: java, windows, hadoop, kerberos

I have setup `kerberos` for windows, secured `hadoop-2.6.0` with `kerberos`.

When submitting job or executing any user commands, Hadoop referring the Kerberos ticket cache from default location **c:\users\username\krb5cc_username**.

I want to change this location at runtime. Is it possible to change the default property of java to refer the ticket cache location from somewhere in my system.

**Updated**

Changing the default location can be done by using the below command

```
kinit -c cache_name username
```

Refer [java kinit](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/windows/kinit.html)

But when i do any operations on hadoop, it takes the default ticket cache location only for user information. How to change the default location into user specific cache location?

Help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I just solved the problem by setting the below environmental variable,

```
set KRB5CCNAME=ticketlocation
```

Setting the above variable makes Hadoop to get the ticket from the specified location.

Comment: I have an issue with the cache location. When I type Klist, it throws the following error.
klist: Credentials cache file '/tmp/krb5cc_1007' not found

Kindly help

Comment: Thankyou .  I have another issue while starting the deamons. I have added the following property in HDFS-SITE.xml

Comment: <property>
        <name>dfs.namenode.keytab.file</name>
        <value>/usr/local/hadoop/etc/hadoop/hdfs.keytab</value>
</property>



<property>
        <name>dfs.namenode.kerberos.principle</name>
        <value>hdfs/env40-node1@TRV.FLYTXT.COM</value>
</property>

<property>
 <name>dfs.namenode.kerberos.internal.spnego.principal</name>
 <value>HTTP/env40-node1@TRV.FLYTXT.COM</value>
</property>

Comment: It still throws the following error. 
java.io.IOException: Login failure for root from keytab /usr/local/hadoop/etc/hadoop/hdfs.keytab: javax.security.auth.login.LoginException: Unable to obtain password from user

Comment: I am installing Kerberos for the first time. Please bear with me if m asking silly question.

Comment: Do you have a keytab file in this location /usr/local/hadoop/etc/hadoop/hdfs.keytab? 
Create a question separately. So that you will get an answer from others too.

Comment: Glad that you replied. I have hdfs.keytab file in that location

Comment: Please correct me if I have gone wrong. First I created a hdfs.keytab file by logging into kdmin.local
xst -norandkey  -k hdfs.keytab hdfs@TRV.FLYTXT.COM

Comment: When I try for cross checking that the particular keytab is assigned for the hdfs user or not by below given command

kinit -kET /usr/local/hadoop/etc/hadoop/hdfs.keytab hdfs@TRV.FLYTXT.COM


Error - 
kinit: Keytab contains no suitable keys for hdfs@TRV.FLYTXT.COM while getting initial credentials

Comment: Why is not matching the hdfs.TRV.FLYTXT.COM user to hdfs.keytab. Kindly help

Comment: When creating keytab file, you have to specify the same principal name. You can list the principals set for that keytab using Java ktab command. Also, verify you keytab generate command.

Comment: Thanks a ton . Iam really grateful to you. Problem resolved

Comment: I have encountered another problem . I have pasted the link for the question below. Please go through the problem and provide some insights. I have been struggling with this problem for past 2 days, Looking forward for your reply.


https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50698220/caused-by-krbexception-server-not-found-in-kerberos-database-7-looking-up

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you can. But you should ask yourself why?

Open a `PrintWriter`, construct your `login.conf`, set the JAAS conf file property from within your code and you're done.

Here is sample code:

```
PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter(new FileOutputSteam("..."));
writer.println("client {");
writer.println("com.sun.security.auth.module.Krb5LoginModule required doNotPrompt=true useTicketCache=true");
writer.print("ticketCache=\"");
writer.print(path);
writer.println("\";");
writer.println("};");

System.setProperty("java.security.auth.login.config", ...);
```

That should do and use JAAS now to obtain a in-memory presentation of the cache.

Comment: Thanks. Can you provide any link for example or explain in detail to make me understand. Hadoop uses its own code, is there any way to do this without modifying any code? I mean is there any file can set with the cache location and make it referable by java?

Comment: @Kumar, please elaborate what you actually try to achieve.

Comment: I want to change the location of kerberos ticket cache using any java runtime argument.

Comment: @Kumar, do you want to move it physically ot simply another cache obtained for another principal?

Comment: Simply obtain for anther principal in different location and java should refer the new cache location.

Comment: Assuming that the cache already exists, this isn't a problem. See my edit.

Comment: Thanks, Can we do the same using any external file (say Jaas.conf) and make it refer by any java runtime parameter?

For eg: java -Djava.auth.conf=c:\jaas.conf program (like this way)

Comment: Yes, it is equivalent.

Comment: @Kumar Kindly help buddy. I have an issue with Kerberos server